# Conservar variables tras un refresco de la página

Tags: php, html, mysql

Tengo hecho un login en el cual lo tengo todo en distintos archivos para organizarlo mejor, el problema llega cuando un usuario se equivoca en los datos y entonces entra en el último else, que reproducirá un texto error en la página del login tras la redirección a ella, pero no lo hace y he intentado de mil maneras. Como dato, utilizo dialogs de JQUERY, por si tiene algo que ver.

dialog_login.php

```
     <?php
    require_once('login.php');
    $error = $_POST['error'];
  ?>
      <div id="dialog1" title="Login user" style="padding-top: 0;display: none;">
      <form method="POST" action="login.php">
        <fieldset class="display_block">
          <label for="usuario_login">User</label>
          <input type="text" name="usuario_login" id="usuario_login" placeholder="smith" autofocus required class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
          <label for="password_login">Password</label>
          <input type="password" name="password_login" id="password_login
          " placeholder="1234567" required class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
          <input type="submit" value="Login" tabindex="-1">
          <p align="center" style="color: red;" ><?php echo isset($error) ? utf8_decode($error) : '' ; ?></p>
        </fieldset>
      </form>
    </div>
```

login.php

```
<?php
require_once('conexion.php');

session_start();

if(!empty($_POST))
{
    $usuario = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['usuario_login']);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['password_login']);
    $error = '';

    $sha1_pass = sha1($password);

    $sql = "SELECT id, id_tipo FROM usuarios WHERE usuario = '$usuario' AND password = '$sha1_pass'";
    $result=$mysqli->query($sql);
    $rows = $result->num_rows;

    if($rows > 0) {
        $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
        $_SESSION['id_usuario'] = $row['id'];
        $_SESSION['tipo_usuario'] = $row['id_tipo'];
        header("location: index.php");
        } else {
            $error = "User or password incorrect";
            header("location: index.php");
    }
}
```

PD: lo de index.php es porque tengo estructurada así la web con requires importando todas las partes de la web en este.

Comment: que es lo que no hace? no muestra el error? no redireccióna?

Comment: Exacto, no muestra el error de la variable, yo creo que es que al redireccionar a dialog_login.php como se refresca la web pierde el valor de la variable y no muestra nada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes guardar el éxito de haberse loggeado en una variable `$_SESSION` y luego en la pagina `index.php` comprobar si esta loggeado o no:

Ejemplo simplificado:

**login.php**

```
<?php
session_start();

// resto de código

if($rows > 0) {

  // resto de código

  $_SESSION['login'] = 1;
  header("location: index.php");

} else {

  $_SESSION['login'] = 0;
  header("location: index.php");
}
```

**index.php**

```
<?php
session_start();

if ($_SESSION['login'] === 0) {

   $error = "User or password incorrect";
}

// resto de código
```

Comment: Funciona perfectamente, era exáctamente lo que buscaba, muchas gracias ! :D

Comment: @Cifu, considera marcar como correcta esta respuesta si era "exactamente lo que buscabas"